# How to access linb.UI.Gallery-ITEM:c:a with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, selector

How to access `id="linb.UI.Gallery-ITEM:c:a"` with jquery?

Rendered by jsLinb i have to access a stupid stupid.. id,
anyone who can help me out plz?

thx sven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select elements by ID using the `#` symbol as a prefix:

```
$('#linb\\.UI\\.Gallery-ITEM\\:c\\:a')
```

If there are dots in the ID of your element, be sure to escape them using a backslash.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/6hqX6/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by access an ID, but if you have a jQuery object you can do this:

```
var id = jQueryObject.attr('id');
```

Comment: <div id="test">blablub</div>
<script>
$("#test").append("<p>some testing</p>");
</script>

normal way.. 

but that seems to be not possible with the id above..

Comment: What does that mean? Are you asking me something?

Comment: access means "how to select.."

Comment: @S-Koluem If you have dots and colons (and other CSS symbols) in your ID, then you will need to scape them. Otherwise jQuery will take them to mean a class or pseudo class. See me other answer for details.

Comment: @S-Koluem well the id you are searching for doesn't match the ID you give. Your comparing "linb.UI.Gallery:b:" and "linb.UI.Group-PANEL:b:"

Comment: @S-Koluem Also it just discovered it has to be `\\` and not just a single one.

Comment: thx .. works perfect.. ;) 
also thx for jsFiddle Link .. nice tool.

Comment: @S-Koluem No problem, and yer jsFiddle is really great, I use it on loads of answers!